# Defining PHP variables - PHP 101

Tags: php, variables

I'm defining the following variables:

```
$rel_path = bloginfo('template_directory');
$thumb_directory = "$rel_path/images/portfolio/";
$orig_directory = "$rel_path/images/portfolio/thumbs";
```

the `$rel_path` is a WordPress function which appears to be printing, however, it is displaying spitting an error message which indicates that `$rel_path` is printing but somehow not being joined with /images/portfolio so the URL is not returning properly

The error looks like this:

> http://localhost:8888/_test_wordpress/wp-content/themes/v3_1_magickThere is an error with your image directory!

Comment: Can you be clearer in your description? Which line gives you the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bloginfo() echoes data instead of returning a string.  You are looking for:

[get_bloginfo()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo)

Comment: echoes, unless echo owns the data.